# Strip Status Label does not display image in Image Margin (Context Menu Strip)

Tags: vb.net, contextmenustrip

I am trying to insert an image into a StripStatusLabel, but for some reason it is not displayed on the left side, like a StripMenuItem.

Inserts are being made in the same way:

```
Dim test As New ToolStripStatusLabel ("Teste")
Dim exiting As New ToolStripMenuItem ("Sair")

test.Image = My.Resources.Test
exiting.Image = My.Resources.Sair

ContextMenuStrip.Items.Insert (0, test)
ContextMenuStrip.Items.Insert (1, exiting)
```

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEXmW.png)

Comment: A ToolStripStatusLabel works best in a ToolStrip or StatusStrip.  Not a menu.  Very unclear why you don't just use a ToolStripMenuItem.

Comment: Because it's only a information label, and it's to be not clickable. I used the context menu strip, because i'm calling from a notification icon. Thanks